# Is there a way to prevent Safari on iOS from clearing the cookies for a website on close?

Tags: ios, cookies, safari, csrf

One of the users of my mobile web app is complaining that he has to log back into the app after every time he goes to use it after he turns his phone screen off. What's happening is Safari clears the cookies for the site when the screen goes off (or when you close safari out completely by double tapping the home button and sliding safari away). If you open safari back up though it will show the last screen you were on but you can't use any session data because it's all gone.

Is there a way to prevent this in safari?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm experiencing the same issue. It's only with mobile Safari.

Comment: as @Marhalpert said below, you need to set a session expiry time other Safari will expire the sessions for you whenever the browser is closed. If you don't have any other reason to expire the sessions I recommend you add this to `initializers/session_store.rb`:

`Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_your_session_name', expire_after: 365.days`

Comment: I've been having this issue for a few days now on latest safari 13 on iOS. I login to my site. Cookie is saved. I confirmed it. I put the tab to background (minimize safari). I open safari again and then iOS auto refreshes the tab, and then deletes the cookie too. So my app gets logged out. Did anyone ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't add an expiry date to your cookie, Safari will add an expiry time of session.

[Exmaple Here - developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Example_4_Reset_the_previous_cookie)