# Vaadin 23 UI recreation after idle time

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

After some idle time on my iPhone when I try to access the previously opened Vaadin page - I see the white screen. I need to force the page refresh in order to render its content.

Also, I see "a new UI has been initialized" event in `UIInitListener`. Looks like the previous UI was destroyed due to user inactivity.

Is there a way to properly reinstantiate UI in such a case without manual page refresh?

Comment: Have you checked out the docs? https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/advanced/application-lifecycle#application.lifecycle.ui-expiration

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, several times. The biggest issue is that I understand that UI will be closed after some missed heartbeat intervals, but don't understand how to properly recreate UI when the user tries to access the view after the idle time in order to avoid the described issue with white page.

Comment: Could this be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233769/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-safari-on-ios-from-clearing-the-cookies-for-a-website

Comment: Something similar was reported at Vaadin's issue tracker lately: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/14803

Comment: @TatuLund I already use `server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age=365d` but the issue still exists